# Append File Content to Another File using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-management

I have a file sample.py that contains a certain code. In sample.py there are some functions that need to be executed. After the execution of those functions. I want to copy all the content from sample.py to temp.py. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In `sample.py`:

```py
##### Your functions
def func1(): # Example
    print("Something")

# ...
    
def main():
    ##### Execute functions
    func1() # Example
    
    # ...



    ##### Copy file

    data = ""

    with open("sample.py", "r") as f:
        data = f.read() # Read contents of 'sample.py'
```

Next, add one of the following blocks

To overwrite 'temp.py':

```py
    with open("temp.py", "w") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

To add to the end of (append) 'temp.py':

```py
    with open("temp.py", "a") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Then add

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```